# Discrete approximation of one step martingale

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

**Definitions:**

Two real valued random variables $X_0$ and $X_1$ are called a *one step martingale* if $E[X_1| X_0] = X_0$.

We say the one step martingale is in $L^2$ if both $X_0$ and $X_1$ are in $L^2(P)$.

**Question:**

Given an $L^2$ one step martingale $(X_0, X_1)$ does there exist a sequence $(Y_0^n, Y_1^n)$ of $L^2$ one step martingales satisfying the following two conditions?

- $Y_0, Y_1$ are simple random variables, i.e. variables taking only a finite number of values.
- $Y_0^n, Y_1^n$ converge to $X_0, X_1$ respectively in $L^2$.

Comment: Why can't you just take a sequence of finite $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal F^n_i$ increasing to $\mathcal F(X_i)$ (the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_i$) and define $Y^n_1=\mathbb E(X_1|\mathcal F^n_1\vee \mathcal F^n_0)$ and $Y^n_0=\mathbb E(X_1|\mathcal F^n_0)$?

Comment: Oh, and the existence of such a sequence would be because $\mathcal F(X_i)$ is countably generated. How does one get $L^2$ convergence from convergence along the filtration though?

Comment: In the case where the $X_i$ are absolutely continuous I think a “by hand” argument suffices, but I’m not sure how to proceed if they’re more singular.

Comment: I think that follows from the pointwise convergence of $Y^n_i$ to $X_i$. We have $\|Y^n_i\|_2^2+\|Y^n_i-X_i\|_2^2=\|X_i\|_2^2$; and since $Y^n_i\to X_i$, we have by Fatou $\liminf \|Y^n_i\|_2^2\ge \|X_i\|_2^2$.

Comment: Ah, right we have a.s. convergence thanks to Doob’s theorem. Thanks! Would you like me to post this as an answer? So that it doesn’t stay “open”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal F_i^n$ be a sequence of $\sigma$-algebras increasing to $\mathcal F(X_i)$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_i$ and let $Y_1^n=\mathbb E(X_1|\mathcal F^n_1\vee \mathcal F^n_0)$ and $Y_0^n=\mathbb E(X_1|\mathcal F^n_0)$.

Then $Y^n_1$ and $Y^n_0$ converge pointwise a.s. to $X_1$ and $X_0$ by Doob's martingale convergence theorem. They therefore converge in $L^2$ to $X_1$ and $X_0$ also.

From the tower law, we see that $\mathbb E(Y^n_1|\mathcal F^n_0)=Y^n_0$.